# Como concatenar nombres de variables en python o Variables dinámicas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un caso:

Tengo una lista con palabras con las cuales quiero asignar unas configuraciones. Esa cantidad de palabras pueden ser 1 o un millón. Voy a representar los números con la letra **N**, siendo está un número entero positivo cualquiera (un int).

lista_palabras = ['palabra1','palabra2',....'palabra**N**']

Estoy tratando de con un ciclo asignar valores a esas palabras y al final usar variables. Ej.

```
i = 1
while i < lista_palabras:
      opts1 = Options()
      palabra1.agumento('mi argumento')
```

El punto es que quiero resolver cuando *i sea igual a 2 o a **N***, los números también me cambien en las variables *opts1 y palabra1*, así:

```
i = 2
while i < lista_palabras:
      opts2 = Options()
      palabra2.agumento('mi argumento')
```

y así sucesivamente:

```
i = N
while i < lista_palabras:
      optsN = Options()
      palabraN.agumento('mi argumento')
```

**¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?**

**Nota1:** *Intenté hacer esto, no me funcionó, pues me creo un diccionario con muchísimas cosas extrañas:*

```
opt=globals()
for i in xrange(10):
  G["opt%d"%i]= Options()
```

**Nota2:** *Soy principiante en Python (2 días)*

**Nota3:** *Uso Python 3 sobre Windows 10*

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Para qué necesitas hacer eso? Lo normal es usar listas o diccionarios para evitar manejar variables individuales.

Comment: Estoy haciendo unos script donde quiero que me habrá una x cantidad de ventanas de un programa con parámetros similares. Pero para ingresar datos distintos. Con eso logró asignar parámetros a diferentes instancias de ese programa.

Comment: palabra1, palabra2, palabra3,...,palabraN podrían ser elementos de una lista, llamemosla palabraList. Así, podrías hacer palabraList[i].argumento('mi argumento'). No veo la necesidad de crear variables con ese nombre específico, para eso existen las listas o los diccionarios.

Comment: Ya había utilizado esa opción. La vi en otro foro, aún no logro tener resultados. Pero entiendo que es la forma correcta.

Comment: ¿Quieres crear variables de forma dinámica? ¿Que es `Options()`?

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de variable es palabraN? ¿Cómo se crea? Una vez que tengas las variables creadas, ¿dónde está el código que hará algo con ellas?

Comment: @CandidMoe es un srt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al igual que como dice @Carlos Pozo (Gracias!) ya había encontrado, por error, en otro foro  alguien que en su código tenía algo como esto y decidí probrarlo Y Funcionó!!!!

```
opts = []
palabra =[]
c = len(opts)
while i <= 8:    
  for elem in range(c):
    opts[i] = Options()
    palabra1.agumento('mi argumento')
```

Sencillamente, todas las palabras(nombres de variables) que se encuentran en las listas las recorro con un `for` y coloco la variable del inidice. A partir de ahí la utilizo como variable tal y como se muestra en el código:

```
opts[i] = Options()
palabra1.agumento('mi argumento')
```

Igual muchas gracias a todos!!

Answer (score 1):

Para que cuando sea igual a 2 o n tienes que poner una condicional ejemplo
If opts2 == 2:

Luego de los : pones lo que quieras que pase cuando se cumpla. Y envés de while utiliza un bucle for. Es más práctico (en mi opinión)para lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Creo que no me has entendido. No saber cuando opts == 2, quiero que optsN cambie al número del ciclo, opts[N] es una variable y quiero asignarle a ese nombre de varible un número según el ciclo.